# Pivot_wider using multiple variables for publication table

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm working on creating a table for publication and an having trouble creating the structure I need.

The "data":

```
a <- data.frame(Year = c(2018, 2019, 2020), a = 1:3,
             b = c("a", "b", "c"),
             c = c("d", "e", "f"), 
             fac = rep("this", 3))
```

The product would look like this ideally.

```
 fac 2018_a 2018_b 2018_c 2019_a 2019_b 2019_c 2020_a 2020_b 2020_c
this      1      a      d      2      b      e      3      c      f
```

I know that his should be possible with the pivot functions, but I'm not sure if I need to pivot longer before I go wider, and all the experiments I've done I can not get the names or data order correct. I'd very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also use the following solution:

```
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = c(a, b, c), 
              names_glue = "{Year}_{.value}") %>%
  select(fac, sort(names(.)[-1]))

# A tibble: 1 x 10
  fac   `2018_a` `2018_b` `2018_c` `2019_a` `2019_b` `2019_c` `2020_a` `2020_b` `2020_c`
  <chr>    <int> <chr>    <chr>       <int> <chr>    <chr>       <int> <chr>    <chr>   
1 this         1 a        d               2 b        e               3 c        f
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I really like the crafty bit with the `{.value}` that was a big stumbling block for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `recast` from reshape2 package:

```
reshape2::recast(a, fac~Year+variable, id.var = c('Year', 'fac'))
   fac 2018_a 2018_b 2018_c 2019_a 2019_b 2019_c 2020_a 2020_b 2020_c
1 this      1      a      d      2      b      e      3      c      f
```

Comment: This absolutely works, thanks for that! I am very curious if there's a `tidyr` solution to this too as I spent quite a while trying to figure it out haha